# add google calendar to outlook calendar using ical

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

google calendars can be added to outlook as internet calendars, using the ical link.

question: If I want my google calendar to keep being updated in outlook, does the google calendar have to be public? Google says that if I make it public, anyone can find my appointments on google search. I think it doesn't sync the changes unless it is public.

is there a better way to sync the two calendars, without the privacy concerns?

office 2016

Answer (score 0):

The only way that actually works properly is to use google apps sync for outlook, but it does mean having to pay £30 per year to use it. It works perfectly with outlook. There is a lot more to it so check online at http://apps.google.com/